# SVG: fill path only applies to border. How can I fill inside shape?

Tags: svg, path, fill

I want to fill the inside of this shape with red. When I use style="fill: red;" it only colors the shape border and not the inside. What attribute should I use to fill inside the shape ?

```html
<svg>
  <path d="M1077.0021,426.94783h-355a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0-,9v228a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0,9,9h355a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0,9-9v-228A9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0,1077.0021,426.94783Zm7,237a7.00778,7.00778,0,0,1-7,7h-355a7.00778,7.00778,0,0,1-7-7v-228a7.00779,7.00779,0,0,1,7-7h355a7.00779,7.00779,0,0,1,7,7Z"
    transform="translate(-113.9979 -130.05217)"
    style="fill: red;"
  />
</svg>
```

Comment: There is a typo in the path. Where it says `a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0-,9`, it should be `a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0,-9,9`.

Comment: Use this d attribute instead: ` d="M1077.0021,426.94783
                      h-355
                      a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0 -9,9
                      v228
                      a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0,9,9
                      h355
                      a9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0,9-9
                      v-228
                      A9.01357,9.01357,0,0,0,1077.0021,426.94783
                      Z
                     "`

Answer (score 2):

There was something wrong in that path. I think it was the `z` in the middle of it all. In some of the arches there was a comma missing. I cleaned up the path and moved it to 0,0.

I used the tool [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) for all of this.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 373 246">
  <path d="m 364 0 h -355 a 9 9 0 0 0 -9 9 v 228 a 9 9 0 0 0 9 9 h 355 a 9 9 0 0 0 9 -9 v -228 a 9 9 0 0 0 -9 -9 z M 371 237 a 7 7 0 0 1 -7 7 h -355 a 7 7 0 0 1 -7 -7 v -228 a 7 7 0 0 1 7 -7 h 355 a 7 7 0 0 1 7 7 z" style="fill: red;" />
</svg>
```

### Update

The inside should also be filled. An alternative could be to split the path into two and then give them a fill each.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 373 246">
  <path d="m 364 0 h -355 a 9 9 0 0 0 -9 9 v 228 a 9 9 0 0 0 9 9 h 355 a 9 9 0 0 0 9 -9 v -228 a 9 9 0 0 0 -9 -9 z" style="fill: darkred;" />
  <path d="M 371 237 a 7 7 0 0 1 -7 7 h -355 a 7 7 0 0 1 -7 -7 v -228 a 7 7 0 0 1 7 -7 h 355 a 7 7 0 0 1 7 7 z" style="fill: tomato;" />      
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is still only the border that shows in red. Any options to color the inside of the shape ?

Comment: @MadeInLagny: your path contains an outer and inner shape (defining the counter shape) – so your stroke is "hardcoded". If you delete the first part of the d attribute (before "M 371") you'll get one solid shape that could be filled.

Comment: @MadeInLagny I added a second example where I split the path into two.